# How add dynamic id to FormattedMessage in react intl

Tags: reactjs, react-intl

I have state area with description field and from server i give state eg. `STARTED`, `FINISH`, `ARCHIVED`.

And i use FormattedMessage for different language like this:

```
<FormattedMessage id={"state." + this.props.state} defaultMessage="defaultState" />
```

It isn't working.

is any solution for this case?

**UPDATE:**
Default state isn't. I load data from server.

My component:

```
class State extends Component {

render() {
    return (
        <Card>
            <CardBody className="text-center">
                <Button className="bg-primary">
                    <FormattedMessage id={"state." + this.props.query.findCourseUserStatus.state} defaultMessage="defaultState" />
                    }
                </Button>
            </CardBody>
        </Card>
    );
}
}

export default createFragmentContainer(
    State,
    graphql`
    fragment State_query on Query {
          findCourseUserStatus(id: $courseId){
          courseId
          state
          }
    },
    `
);
```

Comment: what is your `defaultState` ?

Comment: Where is your state containing `STARTED, FINISH, ARCHIVED` stored ? Can you show us your full component

Answer (score 1):

```
enter code here
```

> Its an old question but i would like to answer it for future
>   reference,

There are two ways:

1. for class component we can use injectIntl as hoc.

   ```
       import {injectIntl } from 'react-intl';

       class State extends Component {
          render() {
             return (
           <Card>
               <CardBody className="text-center">
                   <Button className="bg-primary">
                       {this.props.intl.formatMessage({id:{"state." + this.props.query.findCourseUserStatus.state},
           defaultMessage="defaultState" })}
                   </Button>
               </CardBody>
           </Card>
       );
       }

   }

   export default injectIntl(State);
   ```
2. The upgraded version of react-intl provides with injectIntl hooks for functional component

The usage would be like this.

```
import {useIntl } from 'react-intl';

const State  = (props) {
     const intl = useIntl();
            <Card>
                <CardBody className="text-center">
                    <Button className="bg-primary">
                        {intl.formatMessage({id:{"state." + props.query.findCourseUserStatus.state},
            defaultMessage="defaultState" })}
                    </Button>
                </CardBody>
            </Card>
        );
        }


    export default State;
```

Comment: is there any syntax error? it says unexpected token around `{id: { here`